# Feature selection for a cartesian product of outputs

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

My understanding of feature selection is as follows:

1. Pick an output. This is like the dependent variable of a functions.  Lets call it $Y$.
2. Provide all the columns that may or may not be related to random variable $Y$.
3. Run select-k-best from scikit learn.
4. Now you have the most likely domain, $X$, for a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$.  The set $X$ is a cartesian product of k columns from all the provided columns.

I am wondering if we can set up $Y$ so that it, too, is a Cartesian product of random variables?  Let's say I have $N$ columns and I want to grab $n$ of those columns, turn them into a Cartesian product $Y'$, and then find the k best predictors of this new "feature" which is the Cartesian product.  Can I do this with sci-kit-learn?

In simpler language, I am looking for a known open source package, or an algorithm, to find the best predictors of a multivariate output.

Comment: Are you asking how to select the input features that best predict a multivariate output?

Comment: @user20160 Yes, I think so.